# How to add two field separators to same table by awk?

Tags: awk, field

I have a table like that

100 rows like that and these are first 2 rows:

```
25 Mike Robin 115 DDA
37 Tom  Murray 98 SSM
```

I want to rewrite whole table like this:

```
25_Mike_Robin Mike Robin 115 DDA
37_Tom_Murray Tom Murray 98 SSM
```

I tried:

```
awk '{OFS="_"}; {print $1, $2, $3}  {print $2, $3, $4, $5}' test.txt
```

Output is like that, they are in separate rows and all have same FS:

```
25_Mike_Robin 
Mike_Robin_115_DDA
37_Tom_Murray
Tom Murray 98 SSM
```

Then I tried this, but it gave me a syntax error:

```
awk '{OFS="_"}; {print $1, $2, $3}; {OFS="\t"; {print $2, $3, $4,$5}' test.vcf
```

Comment: What _have_ you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A one-liner:

```
awk '{$1=$1"_"$2"_"$3}1' file
```

Answer (score 2):

Sample input:

```
$ cat input
25 Mike Robin 115 DDA
39 Sarah Cook 223 DDC
127 Elizabeth Johnstone 68 XP3
```

One `awk` idea where we redefine the 1st field:

```
$ awk '{$1=$1 "_" $2 "_" $3; print}' input
25_Mike_Robin Mike Robin 115 DDA
39_Sarah_Cook Sarah Cook 223 DDC
127_Elizabeth_Johnstone Elizabeth Johnstone 68 XP3
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk '{printf "%s_%s_%s %s %s %s %s\n", $1, $2, $3, $2, $3, $4, $5}' <<< "25 Mike Robin 115 DDA"
25_Mike_Robin Mike Robin 115 DDA
```

or

```
awk '{print $1"_"$2"_"$3" "$2" "$3" "$4" "$5}' <<< "25 Mike Robin 115 DDA"
25_Mike_Robin Mike Robin 115 DDA
```